# Vuex Store + PixiJs using Mounted to render too soon?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, pixi.js

If I edit on the code then suddenly the connections will render in the browser, but on initial load in the browser they do no display and its appear the array configConnections is not ready / empty, so do I need to call drawPixi() later somehow ? maybe use nexttick? or am I missing something here should it be async ?

```
<template>
  <div class="connections">
    <canvas id="pixi"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'

export default {
  name: 'ConnectionsLayer',
  computed: mapState({
    configConnections: (state) => state.configConnections,
  }),

  methods: {
    drawPixi() {
      var i
      var canvas = document.getElementById('pixi')
      const app = new PIXI.Application({
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
        antialias: true,
        transparent: true,
        view: canvas,
      })

      let graphics = new PIXI.Graphics()
      graphics.lineStyle(8, 0xcab6ff)

      for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(this.configConnections).length; i++) {
        //start
        graphics.moveTo(
          this.configConnections[i].x_pos_start,
          this.configConnections[i].y_pos_start
        )
        //end
        graphics.lineTo(
          this.configConnections[i].x_pos_end,
          this.configConnections[i].y_pos_end
        )
      }
      app.stage.addChild(graphics)
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.drawPixi()
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can try with watcher and trigger the drawPixi() function from Watcher

Comment: Ok how do I watch my mapState though ?

Comment: Maybe you can figure out some solution from this working example? : https://codepen.io/AsaToBan/embed/roaPBw?height=400&slug-hash=roaPBw&default-tab=js%2Cresult&user=AsaToBan&name=cp_embed_1

Comment: Thank you that’s great and is very similar to how I figured it out so that’s good but it looks like a few better pieces will update and post answer here

Answer (score 1):

```
  <div class="connections">
    <canvas ref="pixi" id="pixi"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'

export default {
  name: 'ConnectionsLayer',
  computed: mapState({
    configConnections: (state) => state.configConnections,
  }),

  watch: {
    configConnections: {
      deep: true,

      handler() {
        this.drawPixi()
      },
    },
  },

  methods: {
    drawPixi() {
      var i
      this.canvas = this.$refs.pixi
      const stage = this.PIXIApp.stage
      let graphics = new PIXI.Graphics()
      graphics.lineStyle(8, 0xcab6ff)

      for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(this.configConnections).length; i++) {
        //start
        graphics.moveTo(
          this.configConnections[i].x_pos_start,
          this.configConnections[i].y_pos_start
        )
        //end
        graphics.lineTo(
          this.configConnections[i].x_pos_end,
          this.configConnections[i].y_pos_end
        )
      }
      for (var j = stage.children.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        stage.removeChild(stage.children[j])
      }
      stage.addChild(graphics)
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    const canvas = this.$refs.pixi
    this.PIXIApp = new PIXI.Application({
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight,
      antialias: true,
      transparent: true,
      view: canvas,
    })
    this.drawPixi()
  },
}
```